# tic tac toe in c - Expected expression - what's wrong?

Tags: arrays, c, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe in c.
I have to ask the user to choose the dimensions ( 3 * 3 / 4 * 4 / ..)
the problem is that it keeps showing me that there is something wrong.. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printBoard(char** board, int size)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
         printf("[%c] ",board[i][j]);
        }
     printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,size;
    printf("Enter the dimensions of the board: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
    if (i != j)
    {
        printf("Input error!");
        return 0;
    }
    if (i == j)
    {
        char **board;
        board = malloc(i*sizeof(char*));
        for(int c=0; c < i; c++)
        {
            board[c] = malloc(c*sizeof(char));
        }
        size = i = j;
        printBoard(char **board,int size); ///  Expected expression - what's wrong?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--   printBoard(char **board,int size); ///  Expected expression - what's wrong?
++   printBoard(board,size);            ///  Fixed
```